# How to use Poetry to Install Dependencies for Multiple Python Projects with Subpackages?

Tags: python, python-poetry

I have the following directory structure in my project:

```
.
├── ./app_core
│   ├── ./app_core/app_core
│   └── ./app_core/tests
└── ./lambdas
    └── ./lambdas/api_lambda
        ├── ./lambdas/api_lambda/api_lambda
        └── ./lambdas/api_lambda/tests
```

Each of the subdirectories ./app_core and ./lambdas/api_lambda contains its own pyproject.toml file for managing dependencies using Poetry.

Is there a way to use Poetry to install all dependencies at once, including the dependencies of the subpackages (./app_core/app_core and ./lambdas/api_lambda/api_lambda)? I want to streamline the process and avoid having to navigate into each subpackage and run poetry install separately.

Comment: Path dependencies: https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#path-dependencies -- But of course, these do not work when distributing via sdists or wheels. -- Otherwise, right a small (Python) script that walks through directories and sub-directories and runs `poetry install` in each.